# Give focus to a field and use HTML anchor

Tags: javascript, html, focus, anchor

I'm making an HTML form, and I want to focus on the first input field when a link on the page is clicked. In addition I want to scroll the page to that location. I wrote a JS function to focus the box:

```
function selectCommentBox() {
    document.getElementById("commentbox").focus();
}
```

and here's the code for my link:

```
<a href='#commentbox' onclick='selectCommentBox();'>Reply</a>
```

My dilemma is that I can only get one behavior or the other. If I use this link as-is, the anchor works correctly and the page is scrolled to the position of the field, but the field is not highlighted. If I add "return false;" to the onclick, the field is highlighted, but the anchor jump is not performed. How can I get both behaviors to apply? Thanks

Comment: Using your code, when I clicked on that link it would scroll me down to the commentbox and have the cursor inside of it (I used a textarea). Am I missing something or does your code work as intended for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an anchor link is followed, you are actually giving the focus to that anchor (#commentbox), so you'll need to write a function that does both the scrolling/linking and the focusing:

```
function selectCommentBox() {
    window.location = '#commentbox';
    document.getElementById("commentbox").focus();
}
```

For old-browser compatibility, add the `return false;` statement and keep the `href` attribute in place.